# Google map center option not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am just starting a new experience with google map API. I am trying to get how it works and I usually understand or find my answers on forums. Maybe i'm missing something? Center is not working.
Google maps marker is always showing on the top left corner
please help me,
Thank you in advance!

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/wgur1z7n/)

JS Code:

```
    var locations = [
      ['<h4>Akouda</h4>', 35.825603, 10.608394999999973],
      ['<h4>Coogee Beach</h4>', 35.874674, 10.571809],
      ['<h4>Hammem Sousse</h4>', 35.886399, 10.591507],
      ['<h4>Kalaa Kebira</h4>', 35.869824, 10.535237]      
    ];

    // Setup the different icons and shadows
    var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';

    var icons = [
      iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',      
      iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
    ]
    var iconsLength = icons.length;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.874674, 10.571809);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.874674,10.571809),
        zoom: 10,     

      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControlOptions: {
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
      }
    });



    var markers = new Array();

    var iconCounter = 0;

    // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: icons[iconCounter]
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));

      iconCounter++;
      // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
      if(iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
        iconCounter = 0;
      }
    }

    $('#myMapModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

});
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(35.874674,10.571809));



    map.setZoom(10);
```

Html

```
    <a href="#myMapModal" data-toggle='modal'> <button onclick="resize();" style="text-align: right;"  class="btn btn-default">Voir sur carte</button></a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myMapModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the center of the map *after* the map has been displayed and has a size (the center of a zero size map/div is in the top left hand corner).  Move your jQuery event handler creation into the `initialize` function so `mapOptions` is in scope, then call `map.setCenter` after you trigger the resize event.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgur1z7n/7/)

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
  })
  $('#contact').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry"></script>
<a class="openmodal" href="#contact" data-toggle="modal" data-id="Peggy Guggenheim Collection - Venice">Contact</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content" id="back">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>Contact</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

pass in some options via a second argument, you specifically want to be using the 'center' property.

`var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.162172, -1.866389),
  zoom: 8,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}`

`map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)`

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `new google.maps.LatLng` and change it to

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat:35.874674, lng:10.571809},
        zoom: 10,
```